# SEO changes in wordpress after permalink changes

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I have installed WordPress in a sub-directory called blog in my root folder. Also, I have served the website from the root following the method given in this [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). My question is, if in future I am planning to create my own website at root and giving a link for blog to the WordPress site in the directory after that. So, then my permalink are going to be changed. If this gonna affect my SEO anyhow. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Comment: so, it'll be good if i give a 301 redirect to the blog sub directory, and after i set up my main site at root location i remove this redirect and add a link to blog on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

Moving any web page ultimately requires a 301 redirect if you wish for Google to pass on any accrued SEO value. If not, the pages will be seen as new and may be seen as *duplicate content*.

Redirection is a great Wordpress plugin for adding 301 redirects quickly and easily. You just provide an incoming URL and where you would like that URL to be forwarded. The Plugin will do the leg work. It also tracks any 404 errors within the site if there are any errors.

**High Level overview of Features**

- 404 error monitoring - captures a log of 404 errors and allows you to easily map these to 301 redirects
- Custom 'pass-through' redirections allowing you to pass a URL through to another page, file, or website.
- Full logs for all redirected URLs
- All URLs can be redirected, not just ones that don't exist
- Redirection methods - redirect based upon login status, redirect to random pages, redirect based upon the referrer!

**References**

- [Redirection Main Website](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/)
- [Redirection Plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/johngodley/redirection)
- [Plugin Download on the Wordpress Plugins Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)